# Not passsing parameter from child component to parent component in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm practicing angular with the latest versions and I'm trying to pass property from child component to the parent component, here are my code in files.
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'udemy-angular';
  serverElements = [
    { type: 'server', name: 'TestServer', content: 'Just a test' }, { type: "blueprint", name: "Test Blueprint ", content: "Test Blueprint!" }
  ];
}
```

app.component.html

```
 <div class="container">
  <app-cockpit></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <app-server-elements
              *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
              [element]="serverElement"
          ></app-server-elements>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cockpit.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent {
  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';

  onAddServer() {
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'server',
      name: this.newServerContent,
      content: this.newServerContent
    });
    console.log("Server Added.");
    
  }

  onAddBlueprint(){
      this.serverElements.push({
        type: 'server',
        name: 'blueprint',
        content: 't'
      })
  console.log("Blueprint Added.");
  
  }

}
```

cockpit.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Add new servers ot blueprints!</p>
        <label>Server Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <label>Server Content</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddServer()">Add Server</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddBlueprint()">Add Server Blueprint</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

server-element.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent {
  @Input() element: { type: string, name: string, content: string };
}
```

server-element.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>
            <strong
                *ngIf="element.type === 'server'"
                style="color: red"
            >
                {{ element.content }}
            </strong>
            <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I run into error of
ERROR

src/app/cockpit/cockpit.component.ts:13:10 - error TS2339: Property 'serverElements' does not exist on type 'CockpitComponent'.

13     this.serverElements.push({

something like that. can you help me to figure out the error.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an error, in your cockpit component:

```
export class CockpitComponent {
  ...
  serverElements: { type: string, name: string, content: string }[] = [];
  ...
}
```

If you need to pass data from child to parent, one of possible ways is https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs